# Passive voice transformation

Tags: syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

Hello my English teacher gave us the following examples about passive voice:

Who painted this picture ?>>>>Who was this picture painted by ?

What caused this track ? >>>What was this track caused by ?

Is this right ? I find that the passive sentence above doesn't make any sense

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your teacher has it right - both of those are correct English, and make sense. There’s quite a good description of the [Passive voice in English](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) on Wiki.

> “The noun or noun phrase that would be the object of an active
>   sentence (such as Our troops defeated the enemy) appears as the
>   subject of a sentence or clause in the passive voice (e.g. The enemy
>   was defeated by our troops).”

So, in the first example the object of ‘painted’ in the active sentence is ‘the picture’, which becomes the subject of the verb ‘painted’ in the passive version. It’s slightly complicated because it’s in the form of a question, so the ‘who was’ makes it more confusing.

> I painted this picture >>> This picture was painted by me.

The above would be a clearer example.